# Get rows data at least one of null in columns MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I had a table look like this(There will actually be more columns in my table).

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
  ID int PRIMARY KEY,
  Name varchar(50),
  teamName varchar(255),
  Create_Date DATETIME
);
```

Here is some sample data

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (1,NULL,'TEST1','2017-01-02');
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (2,NULL,'TEST2',NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (3,'KK','TEST3','2017-01-02');
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (4,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

I want to get rows,which at least one null in the columns.

I had tried this. I got the expect result.

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE  Name IS NULL OR teamName IS NULL OR Create_Date IS NULL
```

**Expect result**

```
| ID |   Name | teamName |          Create_Date |
|----|--------|----------|----------------------|
|  1 | (null) |    TEST1 | 2017-01-02T00:00:00Z |
|  2 | (null) |    TEST2 |               (null) |
|  4 | (null) |   (null) |               (null) |
```

But I don't know if there is an easier way to achieve this effect.

I tried to use IN with IS NULL, but it didn't work.

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE IS NULL IN (Name,Create_Date,teamName)
```

Here is sample data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b678d/1

Comment: `IS NULL IN` is not SQL syntax.  Your first method is the right way.

Answer (score 2):

Just directly check using `IS NULL` if any of the three columns be `NULL`:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE Name IS NULL OR Create_Date IS NULL OR teamName IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't use `IS NULL IN`

> NULL mean I don't know

[Working with NULL Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html)

> the result of any arithmetic comparison with NULL is also NULL, you cannot obtain any meaningful results from such comparisons.

you can use `+` to add all columns if there is a column is `null` in the columns the result will be `null`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE (Name+teamName+Create_Date) IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

there is way of using `IN` but your way is better than this

```
select * from mytable where id in
(SELECT id
FROM mytable
WHERE  Name IS NULL union
SELECT id
FROM mytable
WHERE  teamName IS NULL union
SELECT id
FROM mytable
WHERE  Create_Date IS NULL
)
```